# How to programmatically hide Imageview

Tags: android

I have a linearlayout with three icons as below

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cities"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content          
            android:src="@drawable/city" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/red"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:src="@drawable/red"
            android:visibility="gone" 
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/deal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
            android:src="@drawable/deal" />
```

initially the middle icon is hidden (android:visibility="gone") I have a login screen..when the login i success I want the icon to be visible ..tried as below..but itz not working

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fyelogin);                    
    etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    final ImageView details = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.red); 

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            if(password.equals("guest")){
                lblResult.setText("password successful.");

    giving error @ this line  ----->  details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {
                lblResult.setText("password doesn't match.");
            }

            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: force close....showing error at line :details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Please post the stacktrace you get in logcat.

Comment: here is the log: http://pastebin.com/x10w06dw

Comment: Dude that is a compiler error, Please brush up your basics in OOP language

Comment: @Rakshi.  "Dude", that is a runtime error and has nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line. `details = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.red); `  Step over it.  Is "details" null?

Comment: placed the breakpoint ..no difference ..details is imageveiw

Comment: Try `findViewById(R.id.red).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: And for what reason are you calling finish() if you are calling finish() right after making some change in the view, then user will hardly be able to see the change.

Comment: calling finish because i need to go back to preivious screen right

Comment: teekib I'm going to ask a stupid question, so apologies. Is the TextView you are trying to set to Visible, in the same layout as the one used by this Activity?
Because you can only findViewByID views that are in the same layout and as @Enigma pointed out. If you are calling finish() this will get rid of the current activity.
If you are trying to change the visibility of a view in the previous activity please look into the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)).

Comment: Continuing the previous comment...
You would need to receive the response from the second activity then update the layout of the first **inside** the relevant activity to that view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the ImageView details object a class variable, so that it can definitely be accessed by your listener later.

Comment: Might just be a problem with your copy but there is a missing " for the layout_height of the cities ImageView

Comment: yeahh its a mistake while copying..my bad

Comment: Maybe just try a clean of the project and give it another go.

Comment: Maybe if you could update the question or link to the full code and XML we might be able to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ImageView details;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fyelogin);                    
        etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        details = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.red); 

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                if(password.equals("guest")){
                    lblResult.setText("password successful.");

                     details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    lblResult.setText("password doesn't match.");

                }

                finish();} });
```